# getting textbox value from dynamically created textbox in php

Tags: javascript, php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
</head>
<body>
<form role="form" action="#" method="post" class="f1">

<label>
<input  type="radio" name="optradio" value="3"  count="3">3 
PERSON
</label>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
<tbody id="container">

  </tbody>
 </table>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
  $('input[type="radio"]').click( function(){
$val = $(this).val();
$('#container').html('');
$content = '';
$val = $(this).attr('count')
var i = 1;
for( i = 0; i < $val; i++ ) {
    $content += '<tr><td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="username[]" placeholder="Name" class="f1-email form-control" id="username"></div></td></tr>';
}
   $('#container').html($content);
 });
  </script>
```

how to post the three dynamically created textbox value, for textbox addition i am using the javascript, please check and let me know. i am not able to post the php value to my mail id...

Comment: with javascript we have table.insertRow  and  row.insertCell( ). but your code is in jQuery, so...

Comment: Please don't repost the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You give each textbox a name value (name="name" for instance). For each input you make a php variable, like this:

```
$nameinput1 = $_POST['name'];
```

The `$nameinput1` is the variable wich you will call in your script. This could be anything you want!

The `$_POST['name']` gets the actual info from the `POST` method of your form. Here for it needs to have the exact SAME name at the input element!